# Does useEffect not work with useTransition (Concurrent API)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-concurrent

If I understand (and appreciate) the purpose of `useTransition` correctly, it's to avoid the intermediate "loading" state, as expressed in the [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-lalande-26yep?file=/src/index.js:440-455) from the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-patterns.html#adding-a-pending-indicator):

[image]

The "Loading profile..." text doesn't appear with `useTransition`

But this doesn't seem to work when there's a `useEffect` hook in the mix.

[Here's an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/usetransition-useeffect-issues-ccq5e) taken from [this github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/17272) on the same topic (though slightly different focus)

[image]

There's a "loading greeting" text that appears here.

Is useEffect incompatible with useTransition?

Is it possible to do away with the "loading greeting" text that appears in the second example?